# Should I learn English from the UK if am I learning English from USA?

Tags: learning-methods, english, dialect

I'm learning still English and in some blogs and friends always tell me that I should I learn English from the UK and American at the same time, but for me it is something hard to learn both ways of learning English.

Should I learn English from the UK with English from USA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are **many [varieties of English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dialects_of_the_English_language)**, not just British English (UK) and "American English" (USA) but also Canadian English, Australian English, New Zealand English, Indian English etcetera.

Which variety of English you decide to learn mainly depends on where you live, which variety of English you will need to interact with and the availability of learning materials.

In **Western Europe**, for example, people generally learn British English. (Since the UK is in Europe, this used to make sense.) However, in Russia (as far as I know) and **China**, people learn American English at school. In China, this is due to the USA's dominance in the world. If you live in **Latin America**, it makes more sense to learn American English, because you are more like to need American English than British English or Canadian English.

I also mentioned the availability of **learning materials**. For example, if you live in Europe and you want to learn Australian English (e.g. because you want to move to Australia) and you can't find learning materials for Australian English, it's perfectly fine to learn British English, since Australian English was originally based on British English. But if you learn American English, people in Australia should still be able to understand you. (In fact, most of the problems in understanding will probably be on your side.)

I can't recommend a specific variety of English because the choice depends on factors that aren't mentioned in the question. However, I would recommend making a choice and then **being consistent** in the learning materials you choose, otherwise your English will become a mixture of different varieties of English (e.g. a mixture of American English with something else). Here in Germany, people learn British English at school but they are also exposed to American English through films and other media; as a result, their English is often a mixture of British English (spelling, grammar and vocabulary) and American English (pronunciation and vocabulary) and they are not aware of this inconsistency.

Comment: Indian English can sound delightfully archaic to speakers of other English varieties. True story: I once heard an engineer from India, speaking about a user interface design, say "Whosoever pushes this button...."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand that there are indeed many dialects around the world for English.

With vocabulary in mind, there are differences to words, such as "color" (US) and "colour" (UK).

Grammar can be rather different sometimes (auxiliary verbs like "has" are omitted in American, such as "He already left" instead of "He has already left").

If you want to live in the USA, you should learn ***American English*** for example.

As for the UK, ***British English*** is standard.
With Australia and Canada, there's ***Australian English***, along with ***Canadian English***. A lot of history then.

It's nothing to worry about really. You will get the hang of both of you really want to.

Comment: I know the  different between color and colour but my question is in USA use to english from Uk or not?

Answer (score -3):

They're not so different.

There are some spelling differences, like "color" is "colour", "yogurt" is "yoghurt", etc.